# Is there a method that parses int or returns 0 if unable to do so?

Tags: java, spring, struts

I am constantly having to write  something like this in different places and projects.

```java
int appointmentId =  Integer.parseInt(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getParameter
("appointmentId")) ? request.getParameter("appointmentId"): "0");
```

Is there  a common class that returns parsed int or 0 or something you specify as default return value?

Comment: *"Is there a method that parses int or returns 0 is unable to do so?"*  Sure, the one you write.  The rest of us need to distinguish between actual `0` and an illogical value.

Comment: @AndrewThompson 0 is an illogical number

Comment: Not in the real world it isn't.

Comment: @AndrewThompson in the real world 0 isn't a number at all

Comment: 0 isn't a number? That is news to me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Commons' `NumberUtils.toInt()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#toInt%28java.lang.String%29) returns 0 if the conversion fails.

(And another that lets you specify the default value on conversion failure.)

Answer (score 6):

Just catch the `NumberFormatException` and return 0? It wouldn't be useful to have such a method in the Java API. I mean, with your method you never know if there was an error or not if the method returns 0. So it's only logically that you have to do something like this by yourself.

Something like:

```
public int getInt(String myInt) {
    int i;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(myInt);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        i = 0;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Im curious, as I thought it is a common agreement that using Exceptions as a regular "if-replacement"(e.g. as a logic-flow-controller) is bad practice and that we should try to use methods only according to their contract.
Edit: To make it clear - if you would have to implement a String.isNumeric()-method, would you use parse and catch exceptions or would you use regex?

Comment: an `isNumeric()` method is something else imo because you never need the data from the `parseInt()` method. In this case the primary action is to parse the data. But imo it's already a bad practice to want a feature like this (because now you have no way to tell the difference between 0 or an error).

Comment: I think the method requested by the OP is actually if(isNumeric) parse else return 0.

Comment: Besides, even Apache does it the same way. I'm not saying that it's the ultimate reference, but it seems it's pretty common ot use `NumberFormatException` for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can try with [Ints](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) and the method `tryParse`.

```
int i = Ints.tryParse(Optional.<String> fromNullable(request.getParameter("appointmentId")).or("0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no such method in standard java library. Maybe some external dependencies contain such method, but you have already done this. Just create `Util` class, with static method `parseInt` where implementation is code you pasted.

```
int parseInt(String value, int default)
```

Comment: *"Unfortunately there are no such method in standard java library."*  Unfortunately?  I consider it quite fortunate given 1) The need for this method is very rare. 2) We don't want API bloat with unnecessary methods, **or** the related.. 3) Documentation bloat that would go with that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson unfortunately for OP, as he wants simplest solution. I agree that usage of this method is very rare.

Comment: *"he wants simplest solution"*  Searching through loads of documentation is **not** simple.  So again I do not understand your choice of phrase there.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It can't be *that* rare, since multiple libraries implement it. In the web world most frameworks handle this for you, in a variety of ways, but it's the same process. IME it's not rare at all. Separate discussion from whether or not it should be in the standard API, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton  "*multiple libraries implement it"*  Can't say I'm entirely convinced.  Are those APIs the size of J2SE?  Do those APIs *really* need to implement it?  Perhaps in the context of a web-app. it is not so rare.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's not that rare outside of web apps, either, if the app interacts with anything textual (UI, files, instrumentation/data loggers, ...) Do external APIs "need" to implement it? Of course not, but there's little sense in having it in a zillion places, either, particularly when projects of any size likely already *have* a dependency on something that *does* implement it. It's just local clutter in those cases.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do not mean searching through loads of documentation. If you already know one convenient function you can just use it. Example: how to get value from map by key, or default if key not found in java? Think about boilerplate you write. Syntax `map.get(someKey, defaultValue)` could be very useful, but **unfortunately** java do not support this.